# Is angularJS service singleton?

Tags: angularjs

I have a service method and it will change the value of a boolean variable (false is default value) and return back to controller.
Am calling this service method by clicking on a button.

Consider, am clicking this button and now the variable value is true.
now, am accessing this same service method from another one controller and it is false.. why?

Whats wrong?

first controller,

```
 .controller('myController1',....
$scope.value = false;
$scope.buttonClick = function(){
            $scope.value = myService.setValue(value);
}
```

second controller,

```
.controller('myController2',.....
$scope.value = myService.getValue();
```

service,

```
angular.module('myModule', [])
 .service('myService', ['OtherTypes',
  function (OtherTypes) {

  var   myServiceVariable = false;
   return {
    setValue: function (value) {
                myServiceVariable = !value;
                return (myServiceVariable);
            },

  getValue: function () {
                return myServiceVariable;
            }
}
}
]);
```

Comment: Yes, angular service is singleton. Must be something wrong with your code. Paste some code .:)

Comment: Are you using DI to get the service in the controller?

Comment: yes am injecting the service to controllers. i have updated my question..pls refer it again.

Comment: Is myController2 initialized at the same time as myController1?

Comment: No... this will initialize after controller1.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a typo:  you're separating the two functions with a `,` and not a `;`. Change to:

```
myServiceVariable = false;
setValue: function (value) {
               myServiceVariable = !value;
               return (myServiceVariable);
            };

getValue: function () {
       return myServiceVariable;
   };
}
```

Also, since you're getting the value in the 2nd controller as a return value from a function and not a direct reference to the service variable itself, don't expect it to update automatically. You'll have to call the `getValue()` function everytime.

Comment: yes am calling the getValue() everytime... replacing ; instead , doesn't work :(

Comment: @Dosti Tried debugging in the `getValue()` method? Does it enter the function correctly ?

Comment: @Dosti Should be working correctly.. try placing `console.log('init')` in the service before the declaration of the `myServiceVariable`, and let's see how many times it's called.

Answer (score 0):

hi the following code should show that services are singleton in angularjs.

```
    myApp = angular.module("myApp",[]);

myApp.service("myService", function(){
    myServiceVariable = false;
    return {
        setValue: function (value) {
               myServiceVariable = value;
               return (myServiceVariable);
        },

        getValue: function () {
            return myServiceVariable;
        }
    }
});

myApp.controller("controller1", function($scope, myService){
    console.log(myService);
    $scope.clickHandler = function(){
        myService.setValue(!myService.getValue());
    }
});

myApp.controller("controller2", function($scope, myService){
    console.log(myService);
    $scope.getServiceValue = function(){
        return myService.getValue();
    }
});
```

For a working demo you can go [here](http://jsfiddle.net/chandings/p0zxjevs/1/)

Comment: I can see in my existing code, the module names are different for controller1, controller2 and service. is it creating problem?

Comment: i updated my code so that myService, controller1 and controller2 are all in 3 different modules. all you need to make sure is all the modules you use are included in your main code. 
http://jsfiddle.net/chandings/p0zxjevs/6/
the link to updated code.

Comment: Yes this is the same code i have... Here we are initializing the controllers at the same time. consider if i open a popup window from controller1, then  initializing the controller2, and accessing the getValue() method.

Comment: please take a fork of the fiddle i have shared and updated what you want to do on it. if the problem persists share the link here.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to write the code separately for the popup in fiddle.

Comment: could you share the code for your service. If you are creating a new object in your service, then even if your service is singleton multiple instances of that object will be created.

Comment: in your setValue function you are saving not Value (myServiceVariable = !value;) so if you set value to true it will save false. Is that the behavior you are looking for?

Comment: Yes...this is what expected.

Comment: if you are opening a popup window then you are creating a separate html page and a separate angular app. Thus in effect your service will be a different instance as its a different app. You can use local store if you are creating for modern browser or cookies if it is in same domain and value you are passsing is very small.

Other wise you may try n pass the app object in your pop up window. I have not done anything like it so i do not know if it will work.

Comment: Trying with sessionStorage... but no luck. should I use localStorage?