# forEach in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

I have a method POST in the api and the return i want to filter and put in two differente arrays. If FLG_Alerta is 0 put in array one,if FLG_ALERTA is 1 put in array 2.This is my method and the forEach i'm trying to use,but it doesn't work.

```
vm.filtrarInc = function (Id_Fechamento) {

            id_fechamento = Id_Fechamento;
            $scope.$parent.vm.loading = $http({
                method: 'POST',
                async: false,
                url: _obterUrlAPI() + "AcompanhamentoSilt/FiltroSiltInc",
                dataType: "jsonp",
                params: {
                    Id_Fechamento: Id_Fechamento
                }

            }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                debugger;
                var i = 0;
                var o = 0;
                appModule.forEach(response.data, function (filtro, index) {
                    if (filtro.FLG_ALERTA == 1) {
                        vm.importacaoSiltInc[i] = filtro;
                        i++;
                    } else {
                        vm.importacaoSiltAlt[o] = filtro;
                        o++;
                    }
                });
                //vm.importacaoSiltInc = response.data;
                //vm.importacaoSiltAlt = response.data;
            }, function errorCallback(response) {
                MessageBox("Erro", response.data.Message);
            });
```

Comment: replace appModule by angular: angular.forEach....

Comment: "but it doesn't work" --> How does it not work? Are you getting an error message? How is the expected outcome different from the actual outcome? Specifics, please!

Comment: When it enter in the angular.forEach(response.data, function (filtro, index) i have a error that redirect to the responde message.

Comment: I changed the appModule to angular,and the error is the same of above.

Comment: "and the error is the same of above". You didn't specified any error above, only that "it doesn't work" and that you "have an error". You need to provide more information in order for users to be able to help you.

Comment: My mensage above that says " i have a error that redirect to the responde message"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the problem with your hints.This is my working code.

```
 vm.filtrarInc = function (Id_Fechamento) {

            id_fechamento = Id_Fechamento;
            $scope.$parent.vm.loading = $http({
                    method: 'POST',
                    async: false,
                    url: _obterUrlAPI() + "AcompanhamentoSilt/FiltroSiltInc",
                    dataType: "jsonp",
                    params: {
                        Id_Fechamento: Id_Fechamento
                    }

                })
                .then(function successCallback(response) {
                        vm.importacaoResultado = response.data;
                        angular.forEach(vm.importacaoResultado,
                            function(filtro, index) {
                                if (filtro.FLG_ALERTA == true) {
                                    vm.importacaoSiltInc.push(filtro);
                                } else {
                                    vm.importacaoSiltAlt.push(filtro);
                                }
                            });

                    },
                    function errorCallback(response) {
                        MessageBox("Erro", response.data.Message);
                    });

        };
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code you're calling `appModule.forEach` instead of `angular.forEach`.

Comment: I changed and the error continues.When it enter in the angular.forEach(response.data, function (filtro, index) i have a error that redirect to the responde message

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use the native `map` of [javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). And also you are using a object as a array.

Rewriting your function will be more like this:

```
            id_fechamento = Id_Fechamento;
            $scope.$parent.vm.loading = $http({
                method: 'POST',
                async: false,
                url: _obterUrlAPI() + "AcompanhamentoSilt/FiltroSiltInc",
                dataType: "jsonp",
                params: {
                    Id_Fechamento: Id_Fechamento
                }

            }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                debugger;
                vm.importacaoSiltInc = [];
                vm.importacaoSiltAlt= [];

                response.data.map(function (item, i) {
                    if (item.FLG_ALERTA == 1) {
                        vm.importacaoSiltInc.push(item);
                    } else {
                        vm.importacaoSiltAlt.push(item);
                    }
                });
                //vm.importacaoSiltInc = response.data;
                //vm.importacaoSiltAlt = response.data;
            }, function errorCallback(response) {
                MessageBox("Erro", response.data.Message);
            });
```

TIP: I know this was not asked but I think is good to warn you same bad pratices in your code.

- `$scope.$parent.vm.loading`: is not very cool do this, if you need same object accessible in any place of your application you can do a [service as singleton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28042538/is-angularjs-service-singleton)
- You was using a object as array (I refactored it).

Answer (score -1):

I think you call forEach() function on wrong target.

Try:

`angular.forEach(....`

or:

```
response.data.forEach(function(filtro, index) {
                if (filtro.FLG_ALERTA == 1) {
                    vm.importacaoSiltInc[i] = filtro;
                    i++;
                } else {
                    vm.importacaoSiltAlt[o] = filtro;
                    o++;
                }
});
```

Comment: That's ES5's `Array.prototype.forEach`, not `angular.forEach`.